# Best way to force traffic to Web Front End?

Tags: 2010, web-application, iis, host-header, dns

I have a SP 2010 farm with a 3-tier structure consisting of 1 DB server, 1 App Server and 1 Web Front End.  When I create a Web New Web Application called "Search_WebApp", I notice that it creates the Web Application on BOTH the APP server and WFE.  Right now I added a DNS entry so that all requests to "search" get redirected to IIS on the WFE.  A few questions about this:

1. Why did SP create the Web Application on both the APP Server and WFE? Why not just the WFE?
2. Is a DNS entry and host headers the best/only way to force traffic to the WFE?  I don't want web traffice going to the App Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Because the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service is running on your App Layer.  Go to Central Admin -> Manage services on server, select your App server, then stop this service.

2) DNS entries are the way to target a WFE for end user access.  End users will only go to the WFE DNS is pointed at (or if DNS is pointed at a VIP, to the load balanced WFEs).

Comment: Trevor's answer is 100% correct..just adding another option :) You can also force traffic to your web front end server using hardware load balancers. I highly recommend F5 BigIP's. Here's a [deployment guide](http://www.f5.com/pdf/deployment-guides/f5-sharepoint-2010-dg.pdf) if you are considering making the big purchase.

Comment: If you're running crawl on the app server then I'd keep the Web App Service running and change the host file on it, such that it uses itself as WFE

Comment: For SharePoint 2010, changing the host file isn't required.  You have to set the Web Application's SiteDataServers property: http://blogs.technet.com/b/nathbr/archive/2011/02/22/setup-a-sharepoint-crawl-target-front-end-machine-properly-in-sp2010.aspx