# How to ensure that a server act as a web server and not as application server?

Tags: web-server

I have 3 servers that have SharePoint 2013 installed, how should I know if the servers I named as WFESERVER can really act as web server. There is a question in this group also and someone answered that if a server has a service of **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application** then it can act as web server, but in my case, my APPSERVER has this service also. Kindly enlighten me on this. Do I just need to stop the service **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application** in my APPSERVER so that the WFESERVER servers will act only as web servers?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of Web Front End Server is to serve the http traffic. And it needs to have *Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application* service started. You may choose to stop this service on the App server. You can also keep it started. The main point is that DNS should be configured properly to route the traffic to the WFE.

> DNS entries are the way to target a WFE for end user access. End users
>   will only go to the WFE DNS is pointed at (or if DNS is pointed at a
>   VIP, to the load balanced WFEs).
>   Source: [Best way to force traffic to Web Front End?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50208/best-way-to-force-traffic-to-web-front-end)